# Integration of Duoplane and Quick book Accounting application

Tags: integration, quickbooks

Hi we have completed the integration of Duoplane and Quick book Accounting application. and we are block with the sync of data due to some account settings issue because of that we are unable to proceed further.

Let me know if anyone can help me on this it will be highly appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Exactly what account settings issue are you blocked by? What error message are you getting? Were going to need more details to help you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply actually we are not getting any error message. but when we click on the Export button in Duoplane there is nothing syncing in Quick book software.

Comment: Have you contacted Duoplane support? We're not going to be able to answer this for you -- talk to their support team.